# how to get occupied height and width of gridview item in flutter?

Tags: flutter

how to get gridview item's height and width so that i can design responsive item based on gridview's cross axis count....

```
GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(

                    mainAxisSpacing: 16,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                    childAspectRatio: 0.8,
                    crossAxisCount: 4,//will change its based on requirnment


                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    return CustomContainer(height:??,width:??);
                  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridView's children size depends on `childAspectRatio`.   If you like to provide different size for the itemBuilder, you need to wrap with another widget that will be used to handle the parent constraints.

```dart
class TestGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestGrid({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          final currentViewWidth = constraints.maxWidth;
          final currentViewHeight = constraints.maxHeight;
          bool isLargeScreen = currentViewWidth > 1200;
          return GridView.builder(
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              mainAxisSpacing: 16,
              crossAxisSpacing: 8,
              childAspectRatio: isLargeScreen ? 1.5 : 1.2, //handle the child size
              crossAxisCount: isLargeScreen ? 4 : 2,
            ),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                  final width = constraints.maxWidth;
                  final height = constraints.maxHeight;
                  return Center(
                    //this will take the constraints of GridView.builder, which is comes from `childAspectRatio`
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                      child: ColoredBox(color: index.isEven ? Colors.red : Colors.blue, child: Text("$width x $height")),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can calculate these dimensions using the Mediaquery

example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const int crossAxisCount = 4; //will change its based on requirnment
    const double crossAxisSpacing = 8;
    const double childAspectRatio = 0.8;

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            mainAxisSpacing: 16,
            crossAxisSpacing: crossAxisSpacing,
            childAspectRatio: childAspectRatio,
            crossAxisCount:
                crossAxisCount,
          ),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            // Get the screen width using Mediaquery
            double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

            // Calculate the width of each item taking into account spacing and number of items in axis
            double itemWidth =
                (screenWidth - ((crossAxisCount - 1) * crossAxisSpacing)) /
                    crossAxisCount;

            double itemHeight = itemWidth / childAspectRatio;

            //Change Container to you CustomContainer
            return Container(
              height: itemHeight,
              width: itemWidth,
              color: Colors.red,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```